# Needs to set nodev option on DB directories in linux

Tags: linux, redhat, filesystems, database

I have created two directory for new build linux server & each directory  is 200GB in size and  will be used for DB . security team did scan they found vulnerability as " No nodev option set to directory". I tried with  ""mount -o remount,nodev /mountpoint"" but nodev is not being added in /etc/fstab .

Is it good to add nodev option to DB folder and how I can do this ??

Will unmount the directory and append the line with nodev in /etc/fstab file and remount again will work.
I am new to linux and need help on this topic

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `mount` does *not* modify `/etc/fstab`. It merely remounts the filesystem with the new option, valid until it's remounted with another option, or through a reboot.

You'll have to manually edit `/etc/fstab` to include `nodev`.

If you're unsure of the format, please run `man fstab`. The fourth field of `fstab` contains options.

Comment: Thanks  for reply , Will I have  to unmount the file system before include  nodev in /etc/fstab  ? or editing /etc/fstab is enough

Comment: You don't have to unmount it. `fstab` is only read when mounting it. You can simply do a manual remount *and* edit fstab.

Comment: Thanks this answer worked

Comment: Thanks again  I voted this answer useful . Seems like I don't have enough reputation to vote